# OpenCV cv2.ellipse extension to harder cases

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a mask(not binary but values in range 0-255):

[image]

I'm using `cv2.fitEllipse` like:

```
xy_arr = np.argwhere(mask>0)
xy_arr = xy_arr[:,::-1]
(center_x, center_y), (MA, ma), angle = cv2.fitEllipse(xy_arr)
cv2.ellipse(draw_image, (int(center_x), int(center_y)), (int(MA / 2), int(ma / 2)), int(angle), 0, 360, (0, 0, 255))
cv2.circle(draw_image, (int(center_x), int(center_y)), radius=1, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=1)
```

Result:

[image]

However, expected result:

[image]

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use intermediate values of mask (intermediated values in range 0-255, not only binary mask)
2. How to overcome problem of left side tail, is it possible to cut it off based on curvature?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using morphology to mitigate the tail in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Apply morphology open to smooth out the tail
- Get the non-zero points
- Get the convex hull points
- Fit an ellipse to the convex hull points
- Draw the ellipse on the input
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('blob.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold to binary and invert
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 252, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply morphology open to smooth out tail
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
smoothed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
smoothed = cv2.morphologyEx(smoothed, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# fit ellipse on smoothed image
points = np.column_stack(np.where(smoothed.transpose() > 0))
hull = cv2.convexHull(points)
((centx,centy), (width,height), angle) = cv2.fitEllipse(hull)

# draw ellipse on input image
result = img.copy()
cv2.ellipse(result, (int(centx),int(centy)), (int(width/2),int(height/2)), angle, 0, 360, (0,0,255), 1)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('smoothed', smoothed)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('blob_thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('blob_smoothed.png', smoothed)
cv2.imwrite('blob_ellipses.png', result)
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Morphology smoothed image:

[image]

Resulting ellipse image:

[image]